# What can I use to remove the current and next 20 lines for each match in a file?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a large file (thread dump). I have a bunch of threads named `my-thread-\d+` and if they are waiting, I want to remove that line and the next 20 lines from the file.

for example, I might have a line that looks like:

`"my-thread-1" #628 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=54888.61ms elapsed=194386.85s allocated=80325M defined_classes=4 tid=0x00007f406000c9d0 nid=0xb873 waiting on condition  [0x00007f3faaeed000]`
followed by 20 more lines I don't want.

This pattern will occur multiple times in the file. I would like to run a command against the file that will remove the 20 lines each time there is `my-thread-` followed by `waiting on conditon`.

Comment: @Peregrino69 The \d+ represents an integer (could be 0-1999). I am not sure what you mean by the first question. The input is a thread dump from java (using jstack), the desired output is the same (without the matching thread information).

Comment: Ah. I might add the clarification of `\d+` to the question. I'm not sure how to make the first part clearer... you need to provide the script / command you're trying to use to achieve the goal, and what's the actual result of using that script / command. Without those it's impossible to determine why it might not produce the desired output. If you don't have one, it's unlikely anyone's going to create it for you. There are many roads to Rome; goal being as simple as you stated my simple mind would naturally gravitate towards `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/my-thread-[[:digit:]]/ && /waiting on condition/ {skip = 21}
     skip-- <= 0'
```

If another waiting thread occurs within the skipped lines, `skip` is reset to 21 and 21 lines skipped from there again.

With `pcregrep` (but ignoring further waiting threads inside skipped lines):

```
pcregrep -Mv 'my-thread-\d.*waiting on condition(.*\n){20}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` utility would be mostly useless in this situation as there is no way to exclude lines based on a match on some previous line (a sort of negation of the sense of the `-A` option available in some implementations of `grep`).

I have interpreted the request as wanting to skip the matching line and 20 further lines without looking at those 20 lines to see whether the pattern matches again.

Using a naive approach with `sed` would be to append the following 20 lines to the editing buffer whenever the trigger pattern occurs in the input and then delete it all.

```bsh
sed '/^"my-thread-[[:digit:]]\{1,\}".*waiting on conditon/ { N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d; }' file
```

We could apply a similar approach with `awk`.

```bsh
awk '/^"my-thread-[[:digit:]]+".*waiting on conditon/ { for (i=0; i<20; ++i) getline; next }; 1' file
```

Or, since `awk` knows what line it's on, we may skip 20 lines forward.

```bsh
awk 'FNR < skip_to { next } /^"my-thread-[[:digit:]]+".*waiting on conditon/ { skip_to = FNR+21; next }; 1' file
```

In the code above, `FNR` is the special variable containing the line number in the current file, while `skip_to` is the line number we're skipping forward to when our trigger pattern matches.

Comment: Good approach. But your commands will skip 20 lines, but it does not consider if there is a `my-thread` line within these 20.

Comment: @pLumo The question says nothing about that.

Comment: Yes it does: "remove [...] next 20 lines for **each** match in a file?"

Comment: @pLumo I have made it clear in my answer what interpretation of the question I'm using. Also, if they know they are not interested in the next 20 lines, then why bother looking at them? "... followed by 20 more lines **I don't want**"

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/my-thread-.*waiting on condition/{c=21} !(c&&c--)' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ seq 20 | awk '/3/{c=6} !(c&&c--)'
1
2
9
10
11
12
19
20

$ seq 20 | awk '/3/{c=11} !(c&&c--)'
1
2
```

See [printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern) for details and other related idioms.